# Push Notification Tap Navigation Blazor MAUI Hybrid

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

We are receiving Push Notifications from Firebase like this:

```
 CrossFirebaseCloudMessaging.Current.NotificationTapped += (sender, e) =>
 {
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Tapped");
     //Navigate here
 };
```

We would like to navigate the user to a Blazor MAUI Hybrid page /help when the user taps on the notification. Usually we are using the NavigationManager to change page but how can we utilize inside of the MauiProgram.cs?

Comment: I can't find any way to used the NavigationManager in the MauiProgram.cs. So you may need to do this in the default first razor page.